# Compilation Error on latest version of RCLCPP

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to build the latest version of RCLCPP using Colcon, I get an error saying that a function was not declared in this scope:

```
~/ros2_ws$ colcon build --symlink-install --merge-install --packages-select rclcpp --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
Starting >>> rclcpp  
--- stderr: rclcpp                               
/home/jhassold/ros2_ws/src/ros2/rclcpp/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/publisher.cpp: In member function ‘rmw_qos_profile_t rclcpp::PublisherBase::get_actual_qos() const’:
/home/jhassold/ros2_ws/src/ros2/rclcpp/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/publisher.cpp:202:35: error: ‘rcl_publisher_get_actual_qos’ was not declared in this scope
   const rmw_qos_profile_t * qos = rcl_publisher_get_actual_qos(&publisher_handle_);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/jhassold/ros2_ws/src/ros2/rclcpp/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/publisher.cpp:202:35: note: suggested alternative: ‘rcl_publisher_get_options’
   const rmw_qos_profile_t * qos = rcl_publisher_get_actual_qos(&publisher_handle_);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                   rcl_publisher_get_options
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rclcpp.dir/src/rclcpp/publisher.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/rclcpp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< rclcpp [ Exited with code 2 ]

Summary: 0 packages finished [21.2s]
  1 package failed: rclcpp
  1 package had stderr output: rclcpp
```

I have tried backing up through the master branch, and the error consistently occurs at this commit: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/commit/1f2904f980aaaa7ccbfb40d722795b2d9a55a9aa#diff-2d8789547969c2e91cd5318acd1531c9. Any commits before that on the master branch will build just fine, whereas that one and all future ones will fail (always with the exact same error). The error continues to occur even if I delete my build and install folders, and try to have colcon reconstruct everything.

**HOWEVER** I'm not sure that it's actually that commit's fault - my colleague is able to build rclcpp just fine. Which leads me to think that something got messed up in my environment. However, I don't really know where to start looking.

Has anyone else run into this sort of an issue before? Was it an environment error? And if so, what should I do to make sure that this doesn't happen in future? I'm hoping that I can fix this without having to completely reinstall ROS2...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320334/compilation-error-on-latest-version-of-rclcpp/) by [jhassold](https://answers.ros.org/users/40639/jhassold/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2019-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you have the latest changes of `rclcpp` but not of the other packages, e.g. this `rcl` function was added in https://github.com/ros2/rcl/pull/406.

You need to update *all* your sources (pull the latest changes of all the repositories). To do so you can refer to [Maintaining a Source Checkout](https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Installation/Maintaining-a-Source-Checkout)

And then rebuild your workspace

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2019-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jhassold](https://answers.ros.org/users/40639/jhassold/) on 2019-04-04**:
This seems to mostly work, but during the rebuild workspace step I'm getting an error in the compilation of logging_demo. Specifically that CMake can't find a package configuration file provided by rclcpp_components.

I will triple check and make sure it's been installed...

**EDIT** It wasn't. Apparently it wasn't fond of my forked repository, and refused to download the files from the main repo. I'm going to have to figure out a better way of handling this...

**Comment by [Boston Cleek](https://answers.ros.org/users/68502/boston-cleek/) on 2021-01-28**:
Building ros2 from source is not a great solution.

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2021-01-28**:
It looks like this question/answer is about building the very latest rclcpp, so building all the rest of ROS 2 from source is the only solution.

It is also possible to build just `rclcpp` and use the rest of the packages from the ROS distro, but you must use the right branch. This person could have checked out the [`crystal` branch of `rclcpp`](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/tree/crystal) and built that instead of the latest sources on `master`.